# Apache Flink kafka stream-stream join with watermarking

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a problem with two input stream sources of Kafka events. I need to join the two streams together using **DataStream Interval join** apply a **windowing** to the result of the join and do some aggregation. I have multiple questions,

1. should I apply the watermark strategy (**BoundedOutOfOrderness**) to the eventTime when reading each stream from Kafka Source before doing stream-stream join? If so what does it mean, does it mean that the stream-stream join will be held until the watermark duration is passed and late data will be dropped in the state?
2. if I apply a watermark when reading from the Kafka source, is it still required to apply watermark to the joined stream before using **TumblingEventTimeWindows **based windowing?
3. if I do not want to do a window trigger based on event time and do it based on processing time (**TumblingProcessingTimeWindows**), do I still need to add a watermark to streams before interval joining? and if not, the result of joining be correct? I mean the joined data will appear in the output of interval join based on interval duration whenever they arrive even in out-of-order sort.

I tried to do stream-stream join without watermarking and after that applied a TumblingProcessingTimeWindows based windowing. I don't want to have late data (dropped data) if I use TumblingProcessingTimeWindows and apply watermarking to the streams before joining. If I apply watermarking to the streams before joining even if I use TumblingProcessingTimeWindows, is there a potential situation of losing late events due to applying watermark?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to create your workflow? Also, it's always a good idea to include the version of Flink that you're using.